# java memory issues when removing nodes from a tree

Tags: java, memory, tree, reference

So I learned that in a singly linked list if you remove a node in the middle, the rest of the list will be garbage collected as well since there will be a ripple effect as each node behind it gets dereferenced.

My question is what about a tree where each node has references to it's children as well as a reference to a parent. If I remove a node in the middle(non-leaf node) would that cause a memory leak since it would reference it's children and they would reference it? So if I wanted to remove a subtree, I would have to remove all the nodes in it from the bottom up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about the concept of *reachability*. It is defined in the javadocs, in [the description of the package java.lang.ref](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ref/package-summary.html).

Once an object is not strongly reachable by any thread, it is eligible for garbage collection.

The objects that are strongly reachable by a thread T are:

- objects referenced by local variables in the call stack of T,
- objects referenced by static fields of any classes, and
- objects *(strongly)* referenced by strongly reachable objects.

If you remove a node from the tree you describe (simply by removing the reference on a parent node to a child), and there are no remaining references to the portion of the tree under the node you removed, then those objects are not strongly reachable. Even if they form some kind of cycle, the JVM is smart enough to determine that those objects are not strongly reachable (that is, they reference each other, but none of them can be reached by any code). Therefore, they are eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the start node and remove the reference to that node in its parent.

Comment: but let's say the start node has one child. If i remove the start node wouldn't it's child still reference it and wouldn't it still reference the child thereby leaving both of them with something referencing it?

Comment: Since they are no longer referenced by any other class which has references to it, they will be freed.  The garbage collector is smart enough to determine this.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a subtree you just have to remove the reference to it in its parent.  So long as no other references are held to it **or its children**, it will be garbage collected.